# How to sum up the values selecting from multi-select drop down box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sum up the values selecting from multi-select drop down and display the total in another text/input field .... is there any possible way to do that ?

```js
document.getElementById('amt').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var total = 0,
        selected = this.selectedOptions,
        l = selected.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        total += parseInt(selected[i].value, 10);
    }

    if (!isNaN(total)) {
        document.getElementById('hidden').value = total;
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   <label for="payment_invoice_id" class="col-sm-5 col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label text-left">Invoice No.<sup class="text-red">*</sup> </label>
   <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="invoiceno">
      <select   class="multi-select" multiple='multiple' name="amt[]" id="amt" onChange="document.getElementById('hidden').innerHTML = this.value;">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="5">5Rs</option>
         <option value="10">10Rs</option>
         <option value="15">15Rs</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
   <label for="tax_type" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-7 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Hidden<sup class="text-red">*</sup></label>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">  
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hidden" name="hidden" placeholder="Hidden" autocomplete="off" onChange="sum()" />                                               
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for all your help got the solution...

```
<script>
 $('#amt').change(function () {
    var selected = $("#amt option:selected");
    var sum = 0;
    //console.log($(this).val());
     selected.each(function () {
      var tsum = $(this).val(); 
      sum += Number(tsum);
     });
     $('#hidden').val(sum);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: this is working isn't it ?

Comment: If the field is hidden how do you know its not working?

Comment: no its not working... ... i just named the field as hidden (actually it is supposed to be a hidden field) but i didnt hide that fleld so far ...

Comment: i wanna sum up all the numbers which i am selecting ... eg:5+10+15=30 ...

Comment: Well, it's working, what's your problem exactly?

Comment: i wanna add up the values ... like 5+10+15 and wanna display the result in hidden text box...

Comment: It is already doing that. If you shift+click the values in the box they will be summed up in the hidden field.

Comment: Thanks Danny H ... if we use shift+click its adding up ... since i am using this in a form  we cant expect our customer to do the same ... :(